# pymongo how to upload 20GB file in a fast way into mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying pool() in python:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pymongo import MongoClient
import codecs
import re 
import codecs
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

# read csv file and put the file into database using pymongo
mongo_client = MongoClient('111.111.11.111',maxPoolSize=200) 
db = mongo_client.mydb

def upload(reader):
    for each in reader:
        row={}
        txt = re.split(" ",str(each))
        row["time"] = re.split("'",txt[0])[1]
        row["ticker"] = txt[1]
        row["price"] = re.split("\((.*?)\)", txt[2])[1]
        row["open"] = re.split("\((.*?)\)", txt[3])[1]
        db.price.insert_one(row)

pool = ThreadPool(10) 
results = pool.map(upload, csv.reader(codecs.open('C:\\log.txt', 'rU', 'utf-16')))
```

The idea is to separate the large log.txt file into 10 pieces for 10 pool, and run paralleled to optimize speed. However there's nothing updated in the database, which means my code is not working. What's wrong here? (I am sure the problem is not in uploading function, because if I run without pool() it works fine)

Comment: maybe is better to use an external tool like  mongoimport or logstash

Comment: `mp` requires the existence of ` __main__` , plus  you have only one reader, so no parallelism to exploit

Comment: yes i think you are right valentin, the problem here is that csv.reader(codecs.open('C:\\log.txt', 'rU', 'utf-16')) is not a list but just one whole file, so I need to try to convert that into some elements in one list